# Handling Fault Responses from Spring's WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive

Tags: java, spring, soapfault, webservicetemplate

I'm working with Spring's `WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(Object, WebServiceMessageCallback)` method and I'm having great difficulty understanding how to handle errors properly. Right now I'm calling a SOAP service that will respond with the following message if an error has occurred internally if someone used the same unique identifier.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>BEA-380001</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Internal Server Error</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://www.package.com/CommonEntities/V2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.package.com/package/schema">
                <ns0:FaultDateTime>2014-01-22T10:39:56.056-06:00</ns0:FaultDateTime>
                <ns0:FaultMessage>An application already exists for ID [987654321].</ns0:FaultMessage>
                <ns0:FaultCode>500</ns0:FaultCode>
                <ns0:FaultStack>com.package.package.exceptions.MyException: An application already exists for ID [987654321].
        at com.package.package.endpoints.MyEndpoint.createObject(MyEndpoint.java:71)
        at com.package.package.endpoints.MyEndpoint$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b46dae63.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
        ...More of this stack trace...
```

However, this message is only found by setting the `org.springframework` logging to `trace`. The message that actually makes it back out of my call to `marshalSendAndReceive` is the following much more generic `SoapFaultClientException` message.

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">Internal Server Error</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:Fault xmlns:ns2="http://www.package.com/package/schema" xmlns:ns3="http://www.package.com/package/schema/update">
               <ns2:FaultDateTime>2014-01-22T10:39:56.787-06:00</ns2:FaultDateTime>
               <ns2:FaultMessage>Internal Server Error</ns2:FaultMessage>
               <ns2:FaultCode>2</ns2:FaultCode>
               <ns2:FaultStack>org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Internal Server Error
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:37)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:776)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:539)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:386)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:380)
    at com.package.package.package.adapters.MyAdapter.submitObject(MyAdapter.java:48)
```

How can I grab the `Body\Fault\details\Fault\FaultMessage` from the original response and throw that as an exception in my adapter??

The actual error message from the back end request would be much more useful than a generic SoapFaultClientException and stack trace.

**Package, class and object names were modified using search and replace to extract personal data. If the package or class name seems weird, that's why.**

Comment: Hi Kyle, were you able to find answer for this?

Comment: @Vikky a colleague of mine ended up writing some logic that cycled through the objects and dug down to the actual error I believe. I had forgotten about this question as I was pulled onto other more pressing things and someone else took over. I'll dig through code tonight and try to get a solution up.

Comment: Thanks, I could research that we need to catch SoapFaultClientException. As the Spring whenever sees Faultcode and FaultString in the respoint throuws this exception and has the details of the response in the exception itself. like we can find the fault reason using {ex.getSoapFault().getFaultStringOrReason();</Code> and to get the further details you can browse like <code>e.getSoapFault().getFaultDetail().getDetailEntries(); </code> but still I am not able to get through all the details of response received.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `CclientInterceptor` class that allows that allows for customized client-side message interception.

Check this tutorial out: 
https://codenotfound.com/spring-ws-log-client-server-http-headers.html